# C# The is no implicit reference conversion from 'B' to 'A' using Generics

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, generics

I'm with problems to convert from the type derived to base type using Generics.

Class to manage the dictionary:

```
public class ManagerDictionary<TContext>
{
    public ManagerDictionary()
    {    
        this.Dictionary = new Dictionary<int, TContext>();
    }

    public IDictionary<int, TContext> Dictionary { get; private set; }

    public void Register<TSubContext>(int context, TSubContext subContext) where TSubContext : TContext
    {
        this.Dictionary[context] = subContext;
    }
}
```

Interface of the Process context:

```
public interface IProcessContext : IContext<ProcessViewModel>
{
}
```

My test class:

```
public class Foo<TViewModelContext> where TViewModelContext : ViewModeBase
{
    public Foo(IProcessContext processContext)
    {
        // Create de Dictionary Manager.
        this.ManagerDictionary = new ManagerDictionary<IContext<TViewModelContext>>();

        // Register the process context on dictionary.
        // The error is occurring here: The is no implicit reference conversion from 'IProcessContext' to 'IContext<TViewModelContext>'
        this.ManagerDictionary.Register((int)ContextType.Process, processContext);
    }

    protected ManagerDictionary<IContext<TViewModelContext>> ManagerDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

When I try register the processContext, the problem occurs:

> The is no implicit reference conversion from `'IProcessContext'` to
>   `IContext<TViewModelContext>`

How can I resolve this problem?

**Edit:**

When I Create a inherited class of the Foo, I can register, but I need register on Foo class too.

```
public interface IAnotherProcessContext : IContext<ProcessTwoViewModel>
{
}

public class InheritedFoo : Foo<ProcessTwoViewModel>
{
    public InheritedFoo(IAnotherProcessContext anotherProcessContext)
    {
        base.ManagerDictionary.Register((int)ContextType.InheritedProcess, anotherProcessContext);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to treat `IContext<T>` as if it's covariant with respect to `T`, but that interface isn't defined as being covariant.

Either make the interface be covariant, or alter your program such that you never expect an `IContext<Child>` to be implicitly convertible to an `IContext<Parent>`.

Comment: But when I try create another class that inheirted of the: 'Foo<TViewModelContext>' and try register, it's work, why?

Comment: @RenatoLeite Without knowing what, specifically, you're doing, I couldn't say.

Comment: This does not appear to be exact. `IProcessContext` is implicitly `IContext<ProcessViewModel>` by inheritance. The type parameter `TViewModelContext` is implicitly `ViewModeBase` by generic constraint. We shall assume that `ProcessViewModel` is `ViewModelBase` (their names suggest so). So we have two distinct "specializations" of one class, `ViewModelBase`. Neither covariance nor contra variance of `IContext<>` can help the implicit conversion between `IContext<X>` and `IContext<Y>` when all that is known about types `X` and `Y` is that both specialize the same class `B`.

Comment: @RenatoLeite Why is that not expected?  When you try to treat `IContext<Something>` as an `IContext<Something>` it works, because it really is an `IContext<Something>`, and when you try to treat it as an `IContext<SomethingElse>` it doesn't, because it's not that thing.  That is all exactly as it should be.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen You're right; I didn't notice that.  Why don't you write it up as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I readed about Covariance and Contravariant and solved the problem puting "in" in IContext interface.